# Union of binary cylinder sets

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose, $S=\{0,1\}^\infty$ and say $\Sigma_0 \subset 2^S$, such that 
$$\Sigma_0=\{\{s | s_{i_k}= a_{i_k}, 1 \leq k \leq n,  
a_{i_k} \in \{0,1\}\}, n \in \mathbb{N}, i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \cdots \leq i_k \}$$

Now, if each $A_i \neq \phi$ is a finite disjoint union of sets in $\Sigma_0$ and $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint, can $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ also be a finite disjoint union of sets in $\Sigma_0$?

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $A_i$ be the set of all sequences that begin with $i$ zeroes followed by $1$. These are pairwise disjoint. The union $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ contains all sequences that begin with $0$ and contain at least one $1$. This is not a finite union of cylinder sets. Indeed, if it were, there would be a finite set of indices $I\subset \mathbb N$ such that we can tell whether $a\in E$ based on the values $a_i$, $i\in I$. But there is no such finite set. You can inspect a billion of the first entries of the sequence $0000000\dots$ but that won't tell you if it belongs to $ E$.